# Different results in Two different tabs and same browser window.navigator.userAgent (edge chromium browser)

Tags: javascript, browser, user-agent, navigator, microsoft-edge-chromium

Different results in two different tabs and same browser window.navigator.userAgent

One site says:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36"
```

And One site Says right info:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.42"
```

Edg/90.0.818.42 is missing in the second one.

Did anybody face the same issues? This is super weird

Comment: Sounds like either the web page or an extension is customizing the user agent.

Comment: @Barmar Is there an easy way to debug this?